# Is Postgres ideal for Many to Many data (M:N) which keeps increasing?

Tags: postgresql, scalability

I have a use-case where the data is many to many and needs a wide range of querying functionality.

**Participants and Events**

A User/Participant can register for multiple events. And each event can have many participants. It's a many-to-many relationship.

Consider a data set like this.

- Each event can have 10Million users registered.
- Each User can register a max of 1000 events
- There are 1000 Events running

The following queries are required:

- Query 1. Get all Participants who registered for an event
- Query 2. Get all Events registered by a Participant
- Query 3. Get all Events which are upcoming for a participant

**For handling **Query 1** & **Query 2****

EventParticipantTable : (eventId, participantId) : 1000 x 10M records

**This needs to search 1000 x 10M records?**

The dataset can be split into blocks per eventId to make it ideally scan only 10M records but not sure how this can be handled in PostgreSQL.

**For handling Query 3**

Event Table + EventParticipantTable Join

This needs a join of two tables where I first fetch the Events table for upcoming events(based on start and end timestamps) and for each eventId matched need to find if queried participant id exists in in EventParticipantTable.

**This needs to search 1000 events * (1000 * 10M) event-participant-table entries  ?**

Is 1000 x 10M records per table is not an issue in this scenario?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To resolve your issues, I did the following (all the code below is available on the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=95d4063ae4b694d3b5a5bbdc76681cc5)):

These tests have been run on the db<>fiddle server - we don't exactly know the configuration of the machine(s) nor do we know what else is happening while we're running our queries.

I also ran the tests on my home laptop:

- Linux Fedora 34
- 1TB Samsung SSD
- 4 CPUs, 2 cores
- nothing else running apart from standard Linux processes

The PostgreSQL 12.7 instance was compiled from source with the following options:

```
./configure --prefix=/home/pol/Downloads/db/dba_test/12.7/inst --enable-nls --with-python --with-icu --with-openssl --with-uuid=e2fs
```

The system settings are the defaults except for the recommendations of [pgtune](https://pgtune.leopard.in.ua/#/) as follows:

```
DB Version: 12
OS Type: linux
DB Type: dw
Total Memory (RAM): 32 GB
CPUs num: 4
Data Storage: ssd
```

Recommended changes from defaults:

```
max_connections = 40
shared_buffers = 8GB
effective_cache_size = 24GB
maintenance_work_mem = 2GB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
wal_buffers = 16MB
default_statistics_target = 500
random_page_cost = 1.1
effective_io_concurrency = 200
work_mem = 52428kB
min_wal_size = 4GB   -- used 16GB for this setting
max_wal_size = 16GB  -- used 64GB for this setting
max_worker_processes = 4
max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 2
max_parallel_workers = 4
max_parallel_maintenance_workers = 2
```

The `min_` and `max_wal` settings were bumped up because of stuff I read for systems with heavy writes to speed up loading - shouldn't affect reads - lost references(s)...

Firstly, I created a function to generate random strings (from [here](https://www.simononsoftware.com/generating-random-data-in-postgresql/#generating-random-string)):

```
CREATE FUNCTION random_text(INTEGER)
RETURNS TEXT
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$ 
  select upper(
    substring(
      (SELECT string_agg(md5(random()::TEXT), '')
       FROM generate_series(
           1,
           CEIL($1 / 32.)::integer) 
       ), 1, $1) );
$$;
```

Then, I created an `event` table:

```
CREATE TABLE event 
(
  event_id SMALLINT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  event_name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  event_date DATE NOT NULL
);
```

gave it an index on `event_name` also - I can imagine many scenarios where one would wish to search by name.

```
CREATE INDEX ev_name_ix ON event USING BTREE
(event_name ASC);
```

and also on `event_date`:

```
CREATE INDEX ev_date_ix ON event USING BTREE
(event_date ASC);
```

Then I created 100 (1,000 on laptop) events as follows:

```
INSERT INTO event (event_name, event_date)
SELECT random_text(10), CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '7 DAY'
FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, 100);
```

**BUT!**, you might scream... all the event dates are in the past - yes, but if you do this, then you'll have 50% in the past and 50% in the future:

```
UPDATE event 
SET event_date = 
  (
    CASE 
      WHEN MOD(event_id, 2) = 1 THEN event_date  -- i.e. no change!
      ELSE CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '7 DAY'
    END
  );
```

Checking with `SELECT * FROM event;` - result:

```
event_id    event_name  event_date
       1    A653585119  2021-07-30
       2    01563801BB  2021-08-13
       3    4ED87ABDEC  2021-07-30
       4    EF0394645B  2021-08-13
...     
... snipped for brevity
...
```

Doing it this way (rather than with literal dates) means that the fiddle will work years from now because the `event_date` depends only on when the fiddle is run and not some constant!

The `participant` table:

```
CREATE TABLE participant
(
  participant_id INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  participant_name TEXT NOT NULL  -- might not be UNIQUE
);
```

`participant_name` index:

```
CREATE INDEX par_name_ix ON participant USING BTREE
(participant_name ASC);
```

Then created 10,000 (10,000,000 - 10M on laptop) participants:

```
INSERT INTO participant (participant_name)
SELECT random_text(10)
FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, 10000);
```

Now, our joining table (or [`Associative Entity`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity)):

```
CREATE TABLE ev_par
(
  ev_id SMALLINT NOT NULL,
  par_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT ev_par_pk PRIMARY KEY (ev_id, par_id),
  CONSTRAINT ev_id_fk  FOREIGN KEY (ev_id)  REFERENCES event (event_id),
  CONSTRAINT par_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (par_id) REFERENCES participant (participant_id)
);
```

Now, this is where things become interesting. Running Query 1 on the laptop (see below) gives a response time of ~ 25 mins - **not** ideal!

I tried all sorts of "tricks" (`SET enable_seqscan = off` and `SET enable_bitmapscan = off` - see [here](https://blog.dbi-services.com/can-i-do-it-with-postgresql-14-optimizer-hints/)) - basically, I was just flailing around trying anything I could find on the web...

I finally bit the bullet and went for partitioning - so, what's a logical partition key for the `ev_par` table? Well, the `event_id` appears to be the best candidate - there's 1,000 of them - the entire table (data only) was ~ 350GB so that would give 1,000 tables of ~ 350MB - more manageable!

With indexes (PK + par_ev_ix - see below), the table is ~ 750GB!

So, after the final bracket (`);`) and before the semi-colon, we put:

```
) PARTITION BY LIST (ev_id);
```

I found useful information [here](https://www.enterprisedb.com/postgres-tutorials/how-use-table-partitioning-scale-postgresql) (the most helpful), [here](https://severalnines.com/database-blog/guide-partitioning-data-postgresql), [here](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/partitioning-a-large-table-without-a-long-running-lock/) & [here](https://medium.com/swlh/beginners-guide-to-table-partitioning-in-postgresql-5a014229042).

Basically (simplifying), there are 3 types of partitioning:

- **List**
  `CREATE TABLE customers (id INTEGER, status TEXT, arr NUMERIC) PARTITION BY LIST(status);`
  (parent) and a typical partition would be created by running something like this:
  `CREATE TABLE cust_active PARTITION OF customers FOR VALUES IN ('ACTIVE');`
- **Range**
  `CREATE TABLE customers (id INTEGER, status TEXT, arr NUMERIC) PARTITION BY RANGE(arr);`
  (parent) and a typical partition would be created by running something like this:
  `CREATE TABLE cust_arr_small PARTITION OF customers FOR VALUES FROM (MINVALUE) TO (25);`
- **Hash**
  `CREATE TABLE customers (id INTEGER, status TEXT, arr NUMERIC) PARTITION BY HASH(id);`
  (parent) and a typical partition would be created by running something like this:
  `CREATE TABLE cust_part1 PARTITION OF customers FOR VALUES WITH (modulus 3, remainder 0);`

We now have to create 1,000 partitions using the `LIST` method - so, what do we do, bash script, PL/pgSQL... other? Searching, I found this (Hubert [depesz](https://www.depesz.com/) Lubaczewski's `**absolute gem**`][11](https://www.depesz.com/2021/01/17/are-there-limits-to-partition-counts/)) of a page with the following snippets:

```
$ CREATE TABLE test_ranged (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    payload TEXT
) partition BY range (id);
 
$ select format('CREATE TABLE %I partition OF test_ranged FOR VALUES FROM (%s) to (%s);', 'test_ranged_' || i, i, i+1)
    FROM generate_series(1,10000) i \gexec
```

So, I adapted this code as follows:

```
SELECT FORMAT('CREATE TABLE %I PARTITION OF ev_par FOR VALUES IN (%s);', 'ev_par_' || i, x)
FROM
(
  SELECT LPAD (x, 4, '0') AS i, x
  FROM
  (
    SELECT x::TEXT FROM GENERATE_SERIES (1, 1000) AS x
  ) AS tab1
) AS tab2 \gexec
```

and this generates our desired 1,000 partitions (first two DDL partitioning statements shown):

```
                             format                              
-----------------------------------------------------------------
 CREATE TABLE ev_par_0001 PARTITION OF ev_par FOR VALUES IN (1);
 CREATE TABLE ev_par_0002 PARTITION OF ev_par FOR VALUES IN (2);
```

I left-padded the partition names with `0` so that they would sort correctly when using `\d+ ev_par`.

Finally, we put an index on the "inverse" of the `PRIMARY KEY` for the `ev_par` table - i.e.

```
CREATE INDEX par_ev_ix ON ev_par USING BTREE
(par_id, ev_id);
```

So that searches using `par_id` first will also be indexed.

Before populating the table, I disabled the constraints on the table by running the following command (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42429429/470530)):

```
ALTER TABLE reference DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;
```

and then I populated this by using a [`CROSS JOIN`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-cross-join/) between the two tables.  I split this process into 1,000 separate transactions adapting the partitioning code above as follows:

```
SELECT FORMAT(
'
 BEGIN TRANSACTION;
 INSERT INTO ev_par 
 SELECT e.event_id, p.participant_id 
 FROM event e, participant p 
 WHERE e.event_id = %s; 
 COMMIT;', i)
FROM
(
  SELECT i::TEXT FROM GENERATE_SERIES (1, 1000) AS i
) AS tab1 \gexec
```

So, now we have 1,000,000 records in our ev_par table. On the laptop, this amounts to 10,000,000,000 (10Bn) records. **Be warned** - this takes  approximately 6 hours even with an SSD **and** no constraints!

Then, we reactivate the constraints:

```
ALTER TABLE reference ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;
```

Then, I ran this query (your Query 1 - get all participants who registered for an event):

```
SELECT ep.par_id, p.participant_name
FROM participant p
JOIN ev_par ep ON p.participant_id = ep.par_id
WHERE ev_id = 9;
```

Result:

```
par_id  participant_name
     1        E036FD8DA0
     2        7CC689B41F
     3        E7F1508EE7
     4        3CEF3FC3BD
     5        9BF603F525
...
... snipped for brevity
...
```

But, we require a performance analysis, so I ran

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, TIMING, VERBOSE, COSTS)
<above query>
```

The one line we're interested in was this one:

```
Execution Time: 70.484 ms
```

Pretty impressive! **However**, it wasn't so impressive when run against the 10Bn record table:

```
Execution Time: ~ 25 mins
```

However, after partitioning the data, Query 1 returns:

```
Execution Time: 5795.941 ms
```

So, from 25 mins to 5 seconds - how come?

The answer lies in the plans - the plan for the unpartitioned tables (both fiddle and laptop) are the same:

```
QUERY PLAN
Nested Loop  (cost=0.43..4266.03 rows=5310 width=36) (actual time=0.127..69.629 rows=10000 loops=1)
  Output: ep.par_id, p.participant_name
  Inner Unique: true
  Buffers: shared hit=35545 read=4510 written=1002
  ->  Seq Scan on public.participant p  (cost=0.00..124.85 rows=6985 width=36) (actual time=0.058..2.070 rows=10000 loops=1)
        Output: p.participant_id, p.participant_name
        Buffers: shared read=55 written=13
  ->  Index Only Scan using ev_par_pk on public.ev_par ep  (cost=0.43..4.89 rows=27 width=4) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=1 loops=10000)
        Output: ep.ev_id, ep.par_id
        Index Cond: ((ep.ev_id = 9) AND (ep.par_id = p.participant_id))
        Heap Fetches: 10000
        Buffers: shared hit=35545 read=4455 written=989
Planning Time: 0.167 ms
Execution Time: 70.494 ms
14 rows
```

and for the partitioned data:

```
    QUERY PLAN                                                                                      
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Merge Join  (cost=0.87..635564.73 rows=10000000 width=15) (actual time=0.096..5465.321 rows=10000000 loops=1)
   Output: ep.par_id, p.participant_name
   Merge Cond: (p.participant_id = ep.par_id)
   Buffers: shared hit=152953
   ->  Index Scan using participant_pkey on public.participant p  (cost=0.43..234216.54 rows=9999860 width=15) (actual time=0.032..1234.914 rows=10000000 loops=1)
         Output: p.participant_id, p.participant_name
         Buffers: shared hit=81380
   ->  Index Only Scan using ev_par_0009_par_id_ev_id_idx on public.ev_par_0009 ep  (cost=0.43..251348.54 rows=10000000 width=4) (actual time=0.055..2005.403 rows=10000000 loops=1)
         Output: ep.par_id
         Index Cond: (ep.ev_id = 9)
         Heap Fetches: 10000000
         Buffers: shared hit=71573
 Planning Time: 0.559 ms
 Execution Time: 5795.941 ms
(14 rows)
```

The 2 critical lines are:

```
Non partitioned: ->  Seq Scan on public.participant p 

Parititioned:    ->  Index Scan using participant_pkey
```

In the first case, it scans the entire participant table (10Bn records) and in the second, it uses the participant `PRIMARY KEY` - that's how the query went from 25 mins to 5 seconds!

Then I ran this (Query 2 - get all events registered by a
participant):

```
SELECT ep.ev_id, e.event_name
FROM event e
JOIN ev_par ep ON e.event_id = ep.ev_id
WHERE ep.par_id = 5432;
```

Result:

```
ev_id   event_name
1   CC69EBE53E
2   FD8BD9E311
3   FC94119C5A
4   511EA750E1
5   9956514FAA
...
... snipped for brevity
...
```

And:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE &c... Execution Time: 0.279 ms
```

This query ran on the non-partitioned 10Bn table very quickly also - as it as the only `Seq Scan` is on the small `event` table. Both large tables returned a result in approx. 0.5s!

Plans:

dbfiddle & laptop (non-partitioned):

```
QUERY PLAN
Nested Loop  (cost=0.43..1366.00 rows=5310 width=34) (actual time=0.017..0.270 rows=100 loops=1)
  Output: ep.ev_id, e.event_name
  Inner Unique: true
  Buffers: shared hit=402
  ->  Seq Scan on public.event e  (cost=0.00..22.30 rows=1230 width=34) (actual time=0.008..0.017 rows=100 loops=1)
        Output: e.event_id, e.event_name, e.event_date
        Buffers: shared hit=2
  ->  Index Only Scan using ev_par_pk on public.ev_par ep  (cost=0.43..18.40 rows=27 width=2) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=100)
        Output: ep.ev_id, ep.par_id
        Index Cond: ((ep.ev_id = e.event_id) AND (ep.par_id = 5432))
        Heap Fetches: 100
        Buffers: shared hit=400
Planning Time: 0.109 ms
Execution Time: 0.290 ms
```

Partitioned table:

```
    QUERY PLAN                                                                                
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Hash Join  (cost=35.94..2695.64 rows=1000 width=13) (actual time=0.259..5.333 rows=1000 loops=1)
   Output: ep.ev_id, e.event_name
   Inner Unique: true
   Hash Cond: (ep.ev_id = e.event_id)
   Buffers: shared hit=4013
   ->  Append  (cost=0.43..2657.50 rows=1000 width=2) (actual time=0.016..4.866 rows=1000 loops=1)
         Buffers: shared hit=4000
         ->  Index Only Scan using ev_par_0001_par_id_ev_id_idx on public.ev_par_0001 ep  (cost=0.43..2.65 rows=1 width=2) (actual time=0.015..0.016 rows=1 loops=1)
               Output: ep.ev_id
               Index Cond: (ep.par_id = 5432)
               Heap Fetches: 1
               Buffers: shared hit=4
         ->  Index Only Scan using ev_par_0002_par_id_ev_id_idx on public.ev_par_0002 ep_1  (cost=0.43..2.65 rows=1 width=2) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=1 loops=1)
               Output: ep_1.ev_id
               Index Cond: (ep_1.par_id = 5432)
               Heap Fetches: 1
               Buffers: shared hit=4
...
... 998 more Index Only Scans - snipped for brevity
...
  ->  Hash  (cost=23.00..23.00 rows=1000 width=13) (actual time=0.248..0.248 rows=1000 loops=1)
         Output: e.event_name, e.event_id
         Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 53kB
         Buffers: shared hit=13
         ->  Seq Scan on public.event e  (cost=0.00..23.00 rows=1000 width=13) (actual time=0.029..0.113 rows=1000 loops=1)
               Output: e.event_name, e.event_id
               Buffers: shared hit=13
 Planning Time: 497.960 ms
 Execution Time: 8.995 ms
(5016 rows)

Time: 538.058 ms
```

So, the partitioned table runs an `Index Only Scan` on the 1,000 partitions with a `Seq Scan` on the small `event` table - so it's quick also!

Finally, I ran your Query 3 - all events which are upcoming for a participant. Basically, this simply involves getting the events for a participant (Query 2) and adding a predicate to the `WHERE` clause - `event_date > NOW()` as follows:

```
SELECT ep.ev_id, e.event_name, e.event_date
FROM event e
JOIN ev_par ep ON e.event_id = ep.ev_id
WHERE ep.par_id = 5432 AND e.event_date > NOW();
```

Result:

```
ev_id   event_name  event_date
2   D980DE4C4E  2021-08-13
4   83DC72EF65  2021-08-13
6   CFFF3F2BAC  2021-08-13
8   0B07F148E8  2021-08-13
...
...  snipped for brevity
...
10 rows of 50
```

50 is half of the 100 events. Execution time was 0.4ms (~ 0.5s for both large tables), so we're looking good!

As you can see, the queries with good indexes are pretty fast - obviously you'll have more records in your database, but since we're using BTREEs, the slowdown won't be O(n) - as long as they do use them - the partitioning scheme means that Query 1 does in the large table - not for the unpartitioned one though!

However, I think that the numbers shown give a good indication that PostgreSQL will have absolutely no problems running your queries. If you have a decent server with RAID and SSDs, you'll be humming!

You'll will require more partitions as you add events, but that shouldn't be too onerous - it'll take a couple of minutes at most to fill a single partition.

Obviously, you should benchmark on your own systems to obtain a realistic idea of real world performance for your own users.

So, to answer the question:

> Is 1000 x 10M records per table is not an issue in this scenario?

No, it is **not** an issue!

p.s. welcome to the forum! p.p.s. please **always** include your server version when asking questions!

Comment: In Q1, for an event I will be loading players based on paging only. Won't be loading all 10M records but searching in a table where 1000 events with 10M participants is ideal or not is a question.