# Efficient partitioning of data which is Many-Many (M:N) in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

This is a follow up question to [Is Postgres ideal for Many to Many data (M:N) which keeps increasing?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/297662/is-postgres-ideal-for-datahierarchical-which-keeps-increasing)

To give an overview, Events and Participants are the main entities.
There are 1000 events and 10M participants for each event.

Query : In Event_Participant_Table, Get Participants who registered for an event

The table contains 1000 * 10M records.

Do we need to search all 1000 * 10M records and how efficiently can we partition this in PostgreSQL as previously the query is per defined eventId.

Postgres : 12+

Comment: Why do you say the data is hierarchical - it isn't. Hierarchical data (for me anyway) is CEO -> COO -> Senior Technical Manager -> Project Manager -> Senior Programmer -> Junior Programmer... it's normally various forms of trees - what you have is data which are related in that participants (table) can register for an event (table) - there's no hierarchy here! I was going to edit the previous question, but I thought I'd let you do it - if you agree with me? And I've already more or less answsered this one in my previous answer.I can hack out the answer with the 10Bn benchmark and put it here?

Comment: It's actually at one level tree. Events has Participants. Event 1 -> Event 1 participants, Event 2 -> Event 2 participants ....