# Efficient Partitioning Strategies for PostgreSQL Table with KSUID and High Volume

Tags: postgresql, performance, partitioning, postgresql-14

I'm working with a PostgreSQL table containing terabytes of data, and it grows by millions of rows weekly. Each row is identified by a [KSUID](https://github.com/segmentio/ksuid), and my primary read patterns are:

1. Retrieve a row by its KSUID.
2. List rows by `user_id` in descending order, pagination acceptable.

Currently, the table is unpartitioned and read performance is sluggish. I'm contemplating partitioning the table by month using the KSUID column, [leveraging its embedded uint32 timestamp](https://github.com/segmentio/ksuid#:%7E:text=a%2032%2Dbit%20unsigned%20integer%20UTC%20timestamp), something like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_y2023m09 PARTITION OF ksuid
FOR VALUES FROM ('[current_month_ts][128 zeros]') TO ('[next_month_ts][128 zeros]')
```

This allows each 'Get row by KSUID' query to be isolated to a single partition.

For listing rows by `user_id`, I'm considering keyset pagination:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE user_id = ?
  AND ksuid > last_seen_ksuid
ORDER BY ksuid
LIMIT 10;
```

However, this method still would need to search through multiple partitions depending on `last_seen_ksuid`, but I guess that with an index by `user_id` might be enough.

#### Questions:

1. Is using KSUID as a partitioning key viable, especially given that the column can be represented as text or bytes?
2. Is there a more efficient way to implement listing by `user_id` other than keyset pagination?
3. Are there any pitfalls or performance issues I should be aware of with this approach?
4. Would it be better to just partition based on `created_at` and extract the timestamp from the ksuid on application layer and add it explicitly to the query?

Comment: What do you want to achieve through partitioning? The answer will depend on that.

Comment: speed up the two read patterns that I mention

Comment: Thank you @vérace @laurenz-albe !
We can think of very simple schema (in reality it has like 20 columns)
but the queries are very simple
for example to get the row by id something like: `select * from table where user_id = ? and ksuid = ?`
and for the keyset pagination something like what I've written in the question itself

Comment: for me the value is that they are k-sort (more or less sorted) so when you have an index by ksuid your writes are not so random, your btree doesn't need to rebalance constantly like happens with pure randomness with uuidv4 @vérace

Comment: I don't think so, looking it implementation ksuid is composed by timestamp+randomness 
so the only thing you want extract from them is at which time they where generated with a margin error of 3 seconds
their benefit is to still have a values that you kind of can sort, but you don't care if they are perfect sortable so you don't need a centralized uuid generator and you can distributed the creation across pods and they are not purely random (good for dbs) but not sequential (good as external ids)

Comment: You can delete your own comments up until the last relevant one - it'll stop the move to chat messages. You're asking about whether using KSUID's will help with partitioning - I'd get a better idea if I could see an actual record or two and how you use SQL to extract these timestamps. Check [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/297662/is-postgres-ideal-for-many-to-many-data-mn-which-keeps-increasing/297673#297673) - I used partitioning to get a 25 minute query run in 5 seconds (on a 750GB table) - I'd like to actually **see** how this works in action - it would help me!

Comment: If your search conditions are indexed, queries usually become *slower* with partitioning. A more promising pursuit is to analyze and tune your slow queries. Partitioning can still be useful to keep tables from growing too large, and particularly to get rid of old rows.